# Testing web applications

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, testing

My question so general, but I think the answer will be specific.

All I want to know is:

Is there a way or steps or mechanism to test the application (web application) in a professional way?

Many times when I finish developing and try my application, testing it with dummy data several times, and when I think every thing is okay and I think I have covered all possible scenarios, I find I forgot important issues, or others tell me they found problems in my application.

### How do I overcome this problem, and save my time?

Good links:

### http://www.masukomi.org/talks/unit_testing_talk_2/index.xul?data=slide_data.txt#page215

### http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata

### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185021/rhino-mocks-good-tutorials

### http://daptivate.com/archive/2008/02/12/top-10-best-practices-for-production-asp-net-applications.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/IIS/re-60499_What_is_It_is_an_error_to_use_a_section_registered_as_allowDefinition_MachineToApplication_beyond_application_level.aspx

Comment: http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/10/28/just-where-is-webresource-axd.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570451/how-to-best-do-unit-testing-for-a-web-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a proffesional tester my suggestion is that you should have a healthy mix of automated and manual testing.

**AUTOMATED TESTING**

- **Unit Testing**
  Use NUnit to test your classes, functions and interaction between them.
  http://www.nunit.org/index.php
- **Automated Functional Testing**
  If it's possible you should automate a lot of the functional testing. Some frame works have functional testing built into them. Otherwise you have to use a tool for it. If you are developing web sites/applications you might want to look at Selenium.
  http://www.peterkrantz.com/2005/selenium-for-aspnet/
- **Continuous Integration**
  Use CI to make sure all your automated tests run every time someone in your team makes a commit to the project.
  http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

**MANUAL TESTING**
As much as I love automated testing it is, IMHO, not a substitute for manual testing. The main reason being that an automated can only do what it is told and only verify what it has been informed to view as pass/fail. A human can use it's intelligence to find faults and raise questions that appear while testing something else.

- **Exploratory Testing**
  ET is a very low cost and effective way to find defects in a project. It take advantage of the intelligence of a human being and a teaches the testers/developers more about the project than any other testing technique i know of. Doing an ET session aimed at every feature deployed in the test environment is not only an effective way to find problems fast, but also a good way to learn and fun!
  http://www.satisfice.com/articles/et-article.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio have a great test software

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182409.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/briankel/Visual-Studio-Test-Professional-2010-The-Tool-for-the-Modern-Tester

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a great suite of tools to help test web applications. I'd recommend having a look at that.

Comment: @user418343 - yes it's free (licensed under Apache 2.0 Licence). I'd suggest one of the downloads from: http://seleniumhq.org/download/ . As for which projects to download, check out: http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ to see what they all do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very big subject, there are hundreds of books written about software testing. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) should get you started on some concepts, but you really need to learn a lot more.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850279/recommended-unit-testing-book-for-an-asp-net-mvc-environment) should be useful in choosing a book to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I use http://xunit.codeplex.com in combination with http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/.

Answer (score 1):

Use either ms test framework or NUnit.

I recommend reading about unit tests and focused integration tests.

For full system tests use WatiN.

Answer (score 1):

A lot more than a few nice tools goes into "professionally" testing any application.

But sticking with tools for the moment, a good tools for testing .Net sites is [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).  And a good example of using WatiN in a real world situation is the [DotNetNuke Automation Tests](http://dotnetnukeautomation.codeplex.com/) project.  It is the continually growing set of automated tests that DotNetNuke Corp. is using to test DotNetNuke on a daily basis, and best of all it's open source.